# Not able to get Xpath post applying starts with

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

My HTML Structure:

```
<form id="assignment-submission-540296" action="/assignments/submit-assignment" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input id="assignment_id" type="hidden" value="540296" name="assignment_id">
<input id="assignment_user_id" type="hidden" value="131639273" name="assignment_user_id">
<input type="hidden" value="/assignments/view/540296/131639273" name="returnUrl">
<div style="margin-right:230px;margin-top:-2px">
<input class="by-button fileuploadImage" type="button" value="Submit" data_id="" style="margin-left:155px">
```

My XPATH Generated with FIREPATH Is this:

```
.//*[@id='assignment-submission-540296']/input[4]
```

in the above x path 540296 is dynamic value hence I did something like this. Modified XPATH:

```
.//*[starts-with(@id,'assignment-submission']/input[4]
```

but after this not able to identify the element.

Comment: Show HTML stucture that you would like to find.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a closing parenthesis:

```
.//*[starts-with(@id,'assignment-submission')]//input[4]
                                       HERE ^
```

Also, you needed to use `//` after finding the form to search for desired input anywhere inside the form.

Besides, you can make the xpath a bit more specific by specifying a `form` tag and relying on input type:

```
.//form[starts-with(@id,'assignment-submission')]//input[@type="button" and @value="Submit"]
```